# Unexpected array output on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, select, each

I'm listing a set of data (for simplicity sake, just the identity column) of a particular database table table as follows:

```
<%= @fields.select{|field| field.model=="PreferredOffering"}.each do |field| %>
    <%= field.id %>
    <br/>
<% end %>
```

As you may have gathered from above, I'm using the combination of `select` and `each` to iterate ONLY through rows whose column `model` contains the string `PreferredOffering`.

My expectation was that I would see a nice ordered list of numbers and indeed I do.  My confusion is that I ALSO see the entire `@fields` array coughed all over the page, below the list of numbers.  (See below html excerpt)

```
106
<br/>

107
<br/>

108
<br/>

109
<br/>

110
<br/>

111
<br/>

112
<br/>
[#&lt;PreferredOfferingField id: 5, field_heading: &quot;Anti-dilution provisions- Typical Weighted Average&quot;, category: &quot;Anti-Dilution&quot;, intra_cat_order: 1, model: &quot;P
```

My guess is that I'm doing something funny with `select` as I'm not really familiar with its usage.

Any ideas on how to remedy this would be received gratefully; thanks in advance.

Comment: `<%= @fields.select....` to `<% @fields.select ...`

Comment: @Nithin Ah crap, you're right; here I thought I was going to learn something.  Please feel free to write your comment up as an answer so I can give you credit for proofreading my code. :-P  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%  %>` **Executes the Ruby code inside**

`<%=  %>` **Prints the results**

You are displaying array and then it's values, so you would want to change `<%=  %>` to `<%  %>` .

```
<%= @fields.select{|field| field.model=="PreferredOffering"}.each do |field| %>
```

to

```
<% @fields.select{|field| field.model=="PreferredOffering"}.each do |field| %>
```